# wget boot2docker 1.6.2 windows 7 sh: wget: command not found

Tags: windows-7, boot2docker

Installed `boot2docker` in windows 7.

I tried using wget command and got the following error

> Error: sh: wget: command not found

Please help

Answer (score 1):

`wget` is not necessarily installed in all Linux distributions.

You can use `curl -O <url>` to replace `wget` command.

Comment: thanks though i got wget curl was easier to https .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to start it from the `Oracle VM VIrtualbox Manager`?

If you start it from the icon created on the desktop (or start.sh for what it matters) you get a different command line prompt (git shell in my case). I do have `wget` available when I go through the Virtualbox interface.

Another option is running `boot2docker ssh` from the `Windows Command Prompt`.

Comment: Got it through boot2docker ssh ,will try your approach also thanks

Answer (score 0):

An easiest solution is to install [Gow](http://freecode.com/projects/gow) (Gnu on Windows). It adds 130 Linux commands on your Windows and weigh only 10 Mo.

Here is the list of Linux commands available from **Gow** :

```
agrep, ansi2knr, basename, bash, bc, bison, bunzip2, bzip2,
bzip2recover, cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, cksum, cmp, comm,
compress, cp, csplit, curl, cut, cvs, dc, dd, df, diff,
diff3, dircolors, dirname, dos2unix, du, egrep, env, expand,
expr, factor, fgrep, flex, fmt, fold, fsplit, gawk, gclip,
gfind, gow, gplay, grep, gsar, gunzip, gzip, head, id,
indent, install, join, jwhois, less, lesskey, ln, logname,
ls, m4, make, md5sum, mkdir, mkfifo, mknod, mv, mvdir,
ncftp, nl, od, pageant, paste, patch, pathchk, pclip,
plink, pr, printenv, printf, pscp, psftp, putty, puttygen,
pwd, recode, rm, rman, rmdir, rsync, scp, sdiff, sed,
seq, sftp, sh, sha1sum, shar, sleep, sort, split, stego,
su, sum, sync, tac, tail, tar, tee, test, touch, tr,
type, uname, unexpand, uniq, unix2dos, unrar, unshar,
unzip, uudecode, uuencode, vim, wc, wget, whereis, which,
whoami, xargs, yes, zcat, zip
```

Another solution is to install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), but it is more complicated to install and weigh at minimum 100 Mo (but could be much much bigger, it depends on how many libraries you take).

Hope this could help.